# Concentration on discrete probability estimator

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, measure-concentration

Let $t>1$ and $X_1,..., X_t$ a set of real random variables from a discrete distribution, whose pmf is $p(x)$, supported on the points $1,...,k$.

Let $N_t(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^t \mathbb{1}_{X_i =\, x}.$ It is easy to show that
$$
P\left[\max_x\left|\frac{1}{t} N_t(x) - p(x)\right| <\varepsilon\right] \geq 1- 2k\cdot e^{-2t\varepsilon^2}
$$

by applying a union bound and Bernstein inequality.

**Is there any concentration bound independent of the number of support points $k$?**

Comment: Is $n=t$? Is $X=x$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis yes, thanks for spotting the error

Comment: Still: Is $X=x$?

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$For $[t]:=\{1,\dots,t\}$, we have
$$N_t-tp=\sum_{i\in[t]}J_i,$$
where $N_t$ is the random vector in $\mathbb R^{[k]}$ with coordinates $N_t(x)$ for $x\in[k]$, $p$ is the vector in $\mathbb R^{[k]}$ with coordinates $p(x)$ for $x\in[k],$ and
the $J_i$'s are iid zero-mean random vectors in $\mathbb R^{[k]}$ with coordinates $J_i(x)=1(X_i=x)-p(x)$ for $x\in[k]$. For the $2$-norm $\|J_i\|_2$ of $J_i$ we have
$$\|J_i\|_2^2=\sum_{x\in[k]}(1(X_i=x)-p(x))^2
\le\sum_{x\in[k]}(1(X_i=x)+p(x)^2)=1+\sum_{x\in[k]}p(x)^2\le2.$$

So,
$$P\left(\max_x\left|\frac1t\, N_t(x)-p(x)\right|\ge\ep\right)
=P\left(\max_x\left|N_t(x)-tp(x)\right|\ge t\ep\right)
\le P\left(\|N_t-tp\|_2\ge t\ep\right)
\le2e^{-t\ep^2/4},$$
by [Theorem 3.5](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-22/issue-4/Optimum-Bounds-for-the-Distributions-of-Martingales-in-Banach-Spaces/10.1214/aop/1176988477.full) (with $r=t\ep$, $D=1$, and $b_*^2=2t$). So, we have desired concerntration.

Comment: I have added details on the second inequality in the last display. As for the first **Inequality** there, indeed it follows because $\|u\|_\infty\le\|u\|_2$.

Comment: @Apprentice : Think a bit more about the direction of inequality: If a smaller value exceeds some $u$, then a greater value will exceed $u$.

Comment: Ok thanks @Iosif! Is there any assumption on the probability distribution in order for the concentration bound to hold?

Comment: @Apprentice : There are no assumptions at all in addition to the assumptions stated in your post.

Comment: Also, you mean $\mathbb{R}^k$ and not $\mathbb{R}^{[k]}$ I guess

Comment: Shouldn't $J_i(x)=1(X_i=x)-tp(x)$, is there a $t$ missing? It doesn't look like $J_i$ is a zero mean vector if you define it in the way you do.

Comment: @Apprentice : (i) With your notation such as $p(x)$ rather than $p_x$, it is better to use $\mathbb R^{[k]}$ than $\mathbb R^k$, because $\mathbb R^{[k]}$ is the set of all functions from $[k]$ to $\mathbb R$. Of course, we can identify $p(x)$ with $p_x$, and thus $\mathbb R^{[k]}$ with $\mathbb R^k$. (ii) The definition of $J_i(x)$ is correct, and it is of zero mean, since $E1(X_i=x)=P(X_i=x)=p(x)$.